# geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region undefined in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, geoip

We have a CentOS server which runs php 5.4  and uses fpm. We are running Maxminds GeoIP within our application and we have installed the geoip extension. That in itself might be frowned upon since php.net themselves state state that Maxminds version supersedes the php extension, but nonetheless I have chosen this solution.

I have written a class for our Zend 1 application that gets the timezone for a client based upon the country and/or region code using  geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region method. On our dev environment this works with the main difference being the OS, ubuntu.

However, on the CentOS the call within the Zend application fails. It gives and undefined function on that call. To test whether the extension does in fact work, calling the function outside zend from the command line produces the desired result.

Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like you've only enabled the extension for the CLI version of PHP (which generally has separate configuration to the FPM version). It's a while since I used CentOS though so I can't tell you specifically where to look there.

Comment: What is the output of `php -i | grep geoip` ?

Sometimes on CentOS we had problem with error module compiled with different api than php itself so it didnt load up.

Comment: @Dukecz 
/etc/php.d/geoip.ini,
geoip
geoip support => enabled
geoip extension version => 1.0.8
geoip library version => 1004005
geoip.custom_directory => no value => no value

Comment: @TimFountain I'll investigate since this was a request to our hosting company which resulted in a conflict on one of the servers when they propagated it across the entire set

Comment: @TimFountain the phpinfo() did not show the extension when the php-cli did. Thanks